# If $f$ is differentiable then $f^2$ is differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Question: Proof that if $f:R^2\to R$ differentiable at every point in $R$, then $f^2$ is also differentiable at every point in $R$

My attempt: $f$ is differentiable implies that exists parameters $A,B \in R$ and a function $\epsilon(x,y)$ such that $f(x+x_0,y+y_0)=f(x,y)+A x_0 +B y_0 +\epsilon(x_0,y_0)\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2-(y-y_0)^2}$

And when $(x_0,y_0)\to(x,y) \implies \epsilon(x,y)\to0$

$(a+b+c+d)^2=((a+b)+(c+d))^2=(a+b)^2+(c+d)^2+2(a+b)(c+d)=a^2+b^2+2ab+c^2+d^2+2cd+2ac+2ad+2bc+2bd=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+2ab+2ac+2ad+2bc+2bd+2cd$

Then $f^2(x+x_0,y+y_0)=f^2(x,y)+A(A+x_0+By_0)+B(B+y_0)+\epsilon^2(x_0,y_0)\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}$

We can see that this is very complicated to proof, so I went the other direction and used this:
A function is differentiable at point $P$ if and only if exists tangent line

The tangent plane is given as $z=f(P)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(P)(x-x_0)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(P)(y-y_0)$

Define $g(x,y)=f^2(x,y)$

I can use the chain rule to find a tangent line, however that doesn't help.

What am I missing here? just a hint, I don't want the whole solution otherwise I would not learn anything.

Comment: [Check](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636270/proof-that-the-product-of-two-differentiable-functions-is-also-differentiable) this out for hints

Comment: You mentioned chain rule. Why don't just apply it? As for your proof, the rhs of $f^2(x+x_0, y+y_0)$ looks wonky to me.

Comment: The Derivative of $f^2(x) is 2f.f'(x)$. Showing that the RHS exists for all x may be another approach.

Answer (score 1):

$f'(\mathbf a) = \lim_\limits{\mathbf x\to \mathbf a} \frac {f(\mathbf x) - f(\mathbf a)}{\|\mathbf x-\mathbf a\|}$ exists for all $\mathbf a\in \mathbb R^2$

$\lim_\limits{\mathbf x\to \mathbf a} \frac {f^2(\mathbf x) - f^2(\mathbf a)}{\|\mathbf x-\mathbf a\|} = \lim_\limits{\mathbf x\to \mathbf a} \frac {(f(\mathbf x) - f(\mathbf a))(f(\mathbf x) + f(\mathbf a))}{\|\mathbf x-\mathbf a\|} = \lim_\limits{\mathbf x\to \mathbf a}f'(\mathbf a) (f(\mathbf x) + f(\mathbf a)) $

Comment: $f'(a)$ is a number according to your answer.

Comment: The definition in my book is a bit different, it includes a function s; is it the same definition?

$\lim_\limits{\mathbf x\to \mathbf a} \frac {f(\mathbf x) - f(\mathbf a)-<\mathbf s, x-a>}{\|\mathbf x-\mathbf a\|}$